# Connecting tikz nodes inside the `\for`loop resutls in wrong connection points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to produce the following simple diagram with tikz:

[image]

I would actually prefer to use tikz `\for` loops to put the elements together.  However, the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,>=latex, 
    add/.style={draw=black,circle,inner sep=0pt},
    branch/.style={fill=black,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}%
  ] 
  \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8} {% 
    \node[add] at (-1,\i) (add\i) {$+$}; 
  } 
  \foreach \i[evaluate={\j=\i+1}] in {1,3,5,7} {% 
    \node[branch] at (-1,\i) (dot\i) {}; 
    \draw[->] (dot\i) -- (add\j); 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the wrong figure.  That is, the arrow tips are connected to the right side of the adders:

[image]

while if I just code the `\draw[->]` parts manually outside the loop, that is, to use the following code instead:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,>=latex, 
    add/.style={draw=black,circle,inner sep=0pt},
    branch/.style={fill=black,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}%
  ] 
  \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8} {% 
    \node[add] at (-1,\i) (add\i) {$+$}; 
  } 
  \foreach \i[evaluate={\j=\i+1}] in {1,3,5,7} {% 
    \node[branch] at (-1,\i) (dot\i) {}; 
  }
  \draw[->] (dot1) -- (add2);
  \draw[->] (dot3) -- (add4);
  \draw[->] (dot5) -- (add6);
  \draw[->] (dot7) -- (add8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the correct result (the one I put at the beginning of my question).  Any ideas on why connecting the nodes inside the loop messes up the connection point?

Comment: Please complete your code so we can compile it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `\j in {2,4,6,8}` you were getting `\j in {2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0}` which tried to locate the `0` anchor.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,>=latex, 
    add/.style={draw=black,circle,inner sep=0pt},
    branch/.style={fill=black,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}%
  ] 
  \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8} {% 
    \node[add] at (-1,\i) (add\i) {$+$}; 
  } 
  \foreach \i[evaluate={\j=int(\i+1)}] in {1,3,5,7} {% 
    \node[branch] at (-1,\i) (dot\i) {}; 
    \draw[->] (dot\i) -- (add\j); 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or more simply

```
  \foreach \i/\j in {1/2,3/4,5/6,7/8} ...
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot for your help! Out of curiosity, how could I have understood that I am getting `\j in {2.0,4.0,...}`?  What is the debugging procedure?

Comment: I put {\j} into a node.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[ tikz,
                border =5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,>=latex,
    add/.style={circle, draw=black, inner sep=0pt},
    branch/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt,
                   node contents={} }%
  ]
\foreach \i in {0,2,4,6} 
{%
\node (add\i) [add] at (-1,\i) {$+$};
\draw[->] (-1,\i-1) node[branch] -- (add\i);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives desired result :-)

[image]